# Can i call a method on the same php page also a method in another php code simultaneously on form submit using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

help me! I am a php rookie and i am confused with the php request.

Working on MVC structure for view, I created a HTML form, and on form submit i want to do call two different methods `sendMail()` and `validateData()` available in two different controllers (php file) - say one in `process.php` and another in `register.php` .

On form submit first I want to validate the data and save data to database using `validatedata()`. Then I want to send a verification mail to the user using `sendMail()`.

To handle the request (click event) I am using jquery ajax. Ajax takes a single URL for posting data to the specified URL. So how can I make two different URL requests in a single Ajax call, or say how can I call both the methods in a single Ajax call?
Please suggest me what i should do to solve this issue?
thanks in advance.

Comment: It would make a lot more sense for the validatedata() function in the PHP to simply call the sendMail() function when it has finished and is happy that the data is valid and has been saved. (It's entirely possible for you to make two separate AJAX calls from your page, one after the other, but it's not very efficient compared to making PHP do this task).

Comment: Also, you mention that "sendMail" is in a controller file...but this doesn't make a lot of sense logically. sending mail is a back-end function, it's not directly related to controllers and actions, or to the user interface. It should probably be in a separate class containing email-related utilities, which you can then call from anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Hello @ADyson thanks for replying. Yes doing a synchronous ajax call or say ajax call chaining is not suitable for the performance purpose. Suppose i have to validate large data then it will take more time to finally display the mail sent message. So, think this will fork fine if i have less data to validate. And, sendMail() is the function in my process.php controller which only takes the post data and returns the error or success response to the view, the logic for sending mail to the user is written in a separate php file which is called in the sendMail() function.And its not my issue?

Comment: _"the logic for sending mail to the user is written in a separate php file"_ ...great, so your validation code should call that function after it's validated the data. _" Suppose i have to validate large data then it will take more time to finally display the mail sent message"_ ...ok, but surely you don't want to send the mail if the data isn't valid? If so then you need to wait for validation to complete, regardless of how long it is. But to be honest, unless you have some **very** complex validation requirements then it's unlikely to take such an amount of time that a user would notice.

Comment: Okey, i understood the logic.Thanks ADyson.

Answer (score 1):

A controller should handle an entire request.

So if the user makes (for example) a request asking to create a new user account then *a single controller* should:

1. Validate the data the user has sent to make sure it is what is required before creating an account
2. Create the account in the database
3. Send the email
4. Return a response saying if it worked or if there was an error

So you'll end up with something like

```
{
    $errors = validateData($_POST);
    if ($errors) {
        echo generateErrorPage($errors);
        exit;
    }
    $result = createUserInDBAndSendEmail($_POST);
    showSuccessPage($result);
}
```

(That's *very* rough and ready for the sake of example).

---

Don't divide the steps you need to do to complete the task up between different controllers. Then you only have one URL to worry about.

You can divide the *functions* up between different files and then `include` them.

---

The complete process for creating a user might require additional feedback from the client, e.g.

1. Client makes a request to the CreateUser controller
2. Server creates a user in "unconfirmed" state, sends email to the user and returns an HTML page telling them to check their email
3. User clicks a link in the email to make a request to the ConfirmEmail conroller
4. Server changes the user to "confirmed" and returns a logged in homepage with a welcome message

… and in that case it would have multiple controllers since you need the user to make two different requests.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is really helpful for me.I got it what i want